# Custom report who lines is columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

I need make one custom report in SQL Server. I have one table called ProductsTable, in this table have the products tables of prices.

```
| id | description |
| 1  |   TABLE A   |
| 2  |   TABLE B   |
| 3  |   TABLE C   |
| 4  |   TABLE D   |
```

Now, i have the table ProductsTablePrices with all products prices and his tables.

```
| id | idproduct | idtable | price |
| 1  | 1         | 1       | 1.00  |
| 1  | 1         | 2       | 1.50  |
| 1  | 1         | 3       | 2.00  |
| 1  | 1         | 4       | 5.00  |
```

And finally, i have the Products table.

```
| id |   name   |
| 1  | Paper    |
```

I need create one select to get one result like this...

```
| name  | TABLE A | TABLE B | TABLE C | TABLE D |
| Paper |  1.00   |   1.50  |   2.00  |   5.00  |
```

Thanks!

Comment: What version of `SQL Server` are you using?

Comment: I use SQL Server 2000 @HamletHakobyan.

Comment: @GabrielBiga You can submit a separate answer yourself rather than edit an existing answer to include yours.

Comment: Oh, thanks @BrianDiggs. I will send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Use that to resolve my problem.

```
DECLARE @NameColumnTable VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CountColumns INT
DECLARE @ColumnsPivot varchar(6000)
DECLARE @Flag INT

SELECT @CountColumns = count(*) FROM ProductsTable
SET @Flag = 0

WHILE (@Flag <= @CountColumns)
BEGIN
    SELECT @NameColumnTable = Name FROM ProductsTable
    WHERE id = @Flag
    ORDER BY Name ASC

    SET @ColumnsPivot = ISNULL(@ColumnsPivot,'') + 'SUM(CASE WHEN PT.description = ''' + @NameColumnTable + ''' THEN PP.price END) [' + @NameColumnTable + ']'

    IF @Flag <> @CountColumns
    BEGIN
      SET @ColumnsPivot = @ColumnsPivot + ','
    END

    SET @ColumnsPivot = @ColumnsPivot + CHAR(13)

SET @Flag = @Flag + 1
END

DECLARE @SQLFINAL VARCHAR(5000)

SET @SQLFINAL = 'SELECT  
                   P.name,
                   ' + @ColumnsPivot + '
                FROM Products P
                JOIN ProductsTablePrices PP
                    ON P.id = PP.idproduct
                JOIN ProductsTable PT
                    ON PP.idtable = PT.id
                GROUP BY P.name
                ORDER BY P.name'
EXEC(@SQLFINAL)
```

I don't know if is a good practice, but works great and performance as well.

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT @NameColumnTable = Name FROM ProductsTable`. You have something wrong. It can't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   P.name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN PT.description = 'TABLE A' THEN PP.price END) [TABLE A],
   SUM(CASE WHEN PT.description = 'TABLE B' THEN PP.price END) [TABLE B],
   SUM(CASE WHEN PT.description = 'TABLE C' THEN PP.price END) [TABLE C],
   SUM(CASE WHEN PT.description = 'TABLE D' THEN PP.price END) [TABLE D]
FROM Products P
   JOIN ProductsTablePrices PP
      ON P.id = PP.idproduct
   JOIN ProductsTable PT
      ON PP.idtable = PT.id
GROUP BY P.name
```

Comment: Great code, but not resolve my problem. The ProductsTable is dynamic. The user can add more price tables, is not static. Can you modify the script to get all ProductsTable rows in the columns?

Comment: @GabrielBiga Only dynamic query. Good luck!